# Why does this enum not work?

Tags: c, enumeration

When I compile this code, it gives me

"[Error] unknown type name 'days' ". What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int k=0;
enum days {Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday};

days dayVariable;

printf("Enter number of the day: ");
scanf("%d",&k);

dayVariable=days(k);

printf("%s", dayVariable);

return 0;

 }
```

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168306/print-text-instead-of-value-from-c-enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, enums aren't in the same namespace as normal types. If you want to define a variable typed as that enum, you can do:

```
enum days dayVariable;
```

Alternatively you can define a standard type for your enum. There are many similar ways to do that; here is one:

```
typedef enum {
    /* ... */
} days;
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's C, you must write:

```
enum days dayVariable;

...

dayVariable = (enum days)k;
```

If you want `days` to be the type name, typedef it:

```
typedef enum {Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday} days;
```

Other than that, you use the wrong format specifier in printf.

*P.S.*

And remember, C and C++ are different languages. It's obvious from your code and misconceptions that you come from some C++ background. Try to pick up a book on C programming.

Answer (score 3):

enum is not string. Acutally Monday=0, Tuesday=1, etc. If you want to print string, you may do this:

```
char *days[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", ... "Sunday"};

printf("%s", days[k]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile either:

```
dayVariable=days(k);
```

`days` is not a function, and in C in general type names (which you seem to expect `days` to be) are not functions either. You might mean:

```
dayVariable = (enum days) k;
```

In other words, using a simple cast to the proper type name.

Comment: (enum days) k; seems strange. Do we cast an integer to days? Can you explain this a bit more?