# In C language, the structure contains enum type attributes, how to input and write this structure into a file

Tags: c, file, struct, enums

I've written the Struct Employee and Enum Education. I am going to use "fwirte()" and "fread()" to write and read the file "emp.dat".
But because of the enum, I don't know how to handle it. (Every time you enter a structure variable, it needs to be stored in a file through a linked list.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
enum Education{
    xiaoxue=0,
    chuzhong,
    gaozhong,
    zhuanke,
    benke,
    yanjiusheng
};
struct Employee
{
    char no[7];
    char name[10];
    char sex[2];
    struct date{
        int year;
        int mouth;
        int day;
    }birth;
    enum Education education;
    float salary;
    char telephone[12];
    struct Employee *next;
};
```

Employee information includes employee number, name, gender, date of birth (structure type, display format 2001/01/02), education (enumeration type: 0-primary school(xiaoxue), 1-junior high school(chuzhong), 2-high school(gaozhong), 3-speciality(zhuanke), 4-Undergraduate(benke), 5-Graduate(yanjiusheng)), salary, telephone, etc. (unique employee number, 6-digit string).

Now I want to write a function. This function first creates an employee variable through keyboard input, and then saves it in a file through "fwrite()".
Every time an employee variable is entered, it will be added to the file through the linked list.

When I tried to complete it, the key thing that bothered me was that I didn't know how to assign a value to the Enum property of the structure variable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What I said may not be very clear. Let me edit my question.

Comment: I have revised the content of the question, is it clear enough now? Thanks.

Comment: It may be more clear what your goal is but it's still not clear what the question is. Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: The problem that bothers me the most is that I don't know how to assign a value to the Enum property of a structure variable.

Comment: Have you tried something like `employee.education = chuzhong`?

Comment: The simplest way would be to print out the options to the user (i.e. "0: xiaxue, 1: chuzhong...") and take an int as an input, verify it's in range and use that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `employee.education=2`, and `printf("%d", emp_temp.education);`. The result is "2", but how to make him enter the format of "chuzhong" without using switch?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168306/print-text-instead-of-value-from-c-enum

Comment: The question I asked is indeed not a good question. But with your help, I got a solution. Thanks a lot!